# Adding multiple variables in GraphQL library for dart [flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql

I've been using this dependancy https://pub.dev/packages/graphql to try and use graphql in my app and it works *but* when I need to pass more than one field to the `variables` parameter e.g. `variables: {'cursor': fetchMoreCursor}, {'boney': MamboBattle}` I get the error `_CastError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)` I would have no idea how to add more than one field, does any one know how or am I limited to using just one?

Full Code:

```
static final AuthLink _authLink = AuthLink(
      getToken: () async => 'Bearer $tokenGG',
  );

  static final Link _link = _authLink.concat(_httpLink);

  final GraphQLClient _client = GraphQLClient(
          cache: InMemoryCache(),
          link: _link,
      );

  Future<QueryResult> searchTournys(name, page) async { 

    final QueryOptions options = QueryOptions(
        document: queryStrings(Query.searchTourneys, page),
        variables: <String, dynamic>{ //<-*ERROR HERE*
            'name': name,
            'page': page
        },
    );


  final QueryResult result = await _client.query(options);
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have two distinct maps, instead just add more entries into the first one : `{'cursor': fetchMoreCursor, 'boney': MamboBattle}`

Comment: The `variables` parameter of the function is of type `{Map<String, dynamic> variables}`, I tried passing in the list as so: `final QueryOptions options = QueryOptions(
        document: queryStrings(Query.searchMambo, page),
        variables: <String, dynamic{[
            {'name': name},
            {'page': page}
        ]
        },
    );` but still no size "/

Comment: Oh, my bad I've updated the post should be ok now, just add more entries in the first map

Comment: does this work for you? That was one of the first thing that I tried but I still got the error

Comment: Which error? The same one? The API shows that you need a `Map`: https://pub.dev/documentation/graphql/latest/graphql/QueryOptions-class.html
Please send your full code

Answer (score 0):

If it's a mutation you can just use it like: runMutation({'cursor': fetchMoreCursor, 'boney': MamboBattle})

If it's a query (or you want to use it that way on mutation too), you can should do:
(variables: {'cursor': fetchMoreCursor, 'boney': MamboBattle})

Comment: Got no luck from trying your suggestion "/